# How to add fields to work items in existing team project

Tags: tfs

I have team project in TFS. There are already some work items in the project. I need to add new fields to work item type. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the work item type, add the fields, and re-import it.  As long as you do not delete any fields, this will not affect existing work items.

You may have to bulk-edit existing work items to put in valid values for the newly-added fields.

The best way to do this is by installing the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/), which will add the Process Editor to your Team menu.

Comment: Incidentally, the commands to use for exporting/importing work items are witexport.exe and witimport.exe

Comment: I've added fields via TFS Power Tools. Thank you!